# Allow WPF button navigation via keys with stringformat and _

Tags: c#, wpf, button, string-formatting

Lets say I have a button:

```
<Button Name="BtnOk" 
        Content="OK"
        IsDefault="True">
```

Now when I place a **_** infront of the content, I can use the button with the key that follows after, e.g. I can use the following button directly (without focus onto him) with pressing the key o.

```
<Button Name="BtnOk" 
        Content="_OK">
```

How would I do that with a binding?

I've tried the following two approaches:

1. Doesn't display a `_` at all:

   ```
   <Button Name="BtnOk" 
       Content="{Binding SomePath, StringFormat=_{0}">
   ```
2. Displays the underscore before the letter, instead of underneath him:

   ```
   <Button Name="BtnOk" 
       Content="{Binding SomePath"
       ContentStringFormat="_{0}">
   ```

How do I get the underscore underneath the first letter of the word so navigation can be done with a keystroke of that letter?

---

The button is in a usercontrol that I use from somewhere else, and the text of the button is binded to a dependencyproperty like this:

```
Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}, Path=SomePath}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use `AccessText`:

```
<Button Name="BtnOk" Content="OK"IsDefault="True">
    <AccessText Text={Binding SomePath} />
</Button>
```

**UPDATE**

As your binding doesn't have an underscore you can use `StringFormat` to tackle with.

```
<Button Name="BtnOk" IsDefault="True">
    <AccessText Text="{Binding SomePath, StringFormat=_{0}}" />
</Button>
```

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood - where is the underscore?

Comment: In `SomePath`. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: `SomePath` doesn't have an underscore (its a DP) and I wan't to add the underscore in xaml as you can see in my examples that didn't work

Comment: I'm afraid this has the same problem as `<Button Name="BtnOk" 
    Content="{Binding SomePath, StringFormat=_{0}">` - The underscore is not visible, and navigation via keystroke is not working...

Comment: Why do think so? The `Content` will perfectly ignore the underscore while the `AccessText` intented to deal with. From doc: `Specifies with an underscore the character that is used as the access key.` Have you tried the code?

Comment: Ok, so as it seems, the keystrokenavigation works, but the underscore is invisible. I'll accept the answer anyways, since it achieves what I want mostly. Thank you for you help :)

Comment: Underscope should be invisible initially. You should predd the `Alt` key to make it visible.

Comment: You're right... But they are visible immediately when I set the content to "_SomeThing" and the S is underlined - Interesting...

Comment: Are you sure? It is something strange and probably depends on OS. What OS do you use?

Comment: Windows 7 with SP1

Comment: Anyway, they should behave identically, doesnt matter you set text to the Content or AccessText.